# I want to make sure when a user copies site url from address bar and pastes in some social app the link automatically converts to title of your page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, seo

Just like in airbnb when you copy [url which is copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TypV.jpg)

[when pasted in slack it replaces with this text at top plus site url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wikYi.png)

I have added og:title description images but cannot get it around this one.
Thanks for helping

Comment: Let us know the URL of the page affected by this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`<og:title>` etc is the right way. Sometimes the website where you paste the link will cache the information for a while so you won’t see changes straight away. Try https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/